# Same do-file, same computer, sometimes different results

Tags: stata

I've got a large do-file that calls several sub-do-files, all in the lead-up to the estimation of a custom maximum likelihood model. That is, I have a main.do, which looks like this

```
version 12
set seed 42
do prepare_data
* some other stuff
do estimate_ml
```

and estimate_ml.do looks like this

```
* lots of other stuff
global cdf "normal"
program define customML

    args lnf r noise
    tempvar prob1l prob2l prob1r prob2r y1l y2l y1r y2r euL euR euDiff scale

    quietly {

        generate double `prob1l' = $ML_y2
        generate double `prob2l' = $ML_y3

        generate double `prob1r' = $ML_y4
        generate double `prob2r' = $ML_y5

        generate double `scale' = 1/100

        generate double `y1l' = `scale'*((($ML_y10+$ML_y6)^(1-`r'))/(1-`r'))
        generate double `y2l' = `scale'*((($ML_y10+$ML_y7)^(1-`r'))/(1-`r'))
        generate double `y1r' = `scale'*((($ML_y10+$ML_y8)^(1-`r'))/(1-`r'))
        generate double `y2r' = `scale'*((($ML_y10+$ML_y9)^(1-`r'))/(1-`r'))

        generate double `euL' = (`prob1l'*`y1l')+(`prob2l'*`y2l')
        generate double `euR' = (`prob1r'*`y1r')+(`prob2r'*`y2r')

        generate double `euDiff' = (`euR'-`euL')/`noise'

        replace `lnf' = ln($cdf( `euDiff')) if $ML_y1==1
        replace `lnf' = ln($cdf(-`euDiff')) if $ML_y1==0
    }

end
ml model lf customML ... , maximize technique(nr) difficult cluster(id)
ml display
```

To my great surprise, when I run the whole thing from top to bottom in Stata 12/SE I get different results for one of the coefficients reported by `ml display` each time I run it.

At first I thought this was a problem of running the same code on different computers but the issue occurs even if I run the same code on the same machine multiple times. Then I thought this was a random number generator issue but, as you can see, I can reproduce the issue even if I fix the seed at the beginning of the main do-file. The same holds when I move the `set seed` command immediately above the `ml model...`. The only way to get the same results though multiple runs is if I run everything above `ml model` and then only run `ml model` and `ml display` repeatedly.

I know that the likelihood function is very flat in the direction of the parameter whose value changes over runs so it's no surprise it *can* change. But I don't understand why it would, given that there seems to be little that isn't deterministic in my do files to begin with and nothing that couldn't be made deterministic by fixing the seed.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a problem with sorting. The default behaviour is that if two observations have the same value, they will be sorted randomly. Moreover, the random process that guides this sorting is governed by a different seed. This is intentional, as it prevents users to by accident see consistency where none exist. The logic being that it is better to be puzzled than to be overly confident.

Comment: Indeed. There's an innocent-looking `sort` in there somewhere that seems to make all the difference. What I don't understand is why the mere sorting of a data set would make any difference in the estimation. It's not the case that the sorting changes the data that gets used in the estimation substantially. In fact I can resort the data in a way that no randomness plays a role just before I run the `ml model` and that gets rid of any differences that may be generated earlier in the do-file.

Comment: Also, is there any way to set the seed that governs the sorting?

Comment: I guess I can answer that second question myself: the command seems to be `set sortseed`.

Comment: In order to confirm that `sort` is causing the problem, you can simply use the `stable` option with `sort`. If the `sort` is the cause, then with `stable` you should get the same results. However, using that other than for diagnostics can get you in trouble; the same applies to using `set sortseed`. You need to find the source of the randomness and fix it. Read for example Stata tip 28: Precise control of dataset sort order by L. Philip Schumm.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertoFerrer. I had already found another way of confirming that the sort was the culprit. Sorting the data again right before the `ml model` call and sorting it on a combination of variables that made the ordering unique got rid of the differences between runs. So, presumably, would setting the `sortseed` (Haven't actually tried this yet). What I still don't understand is why the mere fact that the data are sorted differently would change the estimation result.

Comment: The problem is just a Probit with a non-linear latent index. The log-likelihood is the sum of the individual log-likelihoods and I don't understand why the order in which things are calculated/added would make any difference for the result.

Comment: If there are ties, then `sort` deliberately breaks them at random from run to run. The variation in results may or may not be trivial, but `set sort, stable` and `set sortseed` will hide the phenomenon and give a false impression of consistency. See: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/lang/sort.html .

Comment: @SteveSamuels I get that. I get that sort isn't a stable sort. I also get that because sort isn't a stable sort later commands which rely on the data being sorted in a particular way may give me different results every time I run the script. What I don't get is why a calculation which I don't think would depend on the sort nevertheless gives me different answers every time I run the do-file.

Comment: The calculations are: taking a linear combination of variables from the data set weighted by a coefficient vector. Taking the resulting numbers, call them $g_i$, and using them to calculate something like $x^{g_i}-y^{g_i}$, then passing this to the normal CDF, then multiplying this result by another variable in the data set and finally summing this over all observations. That's my likelihood and I see neither a dependence on the sorting of the data nor on anything random in there. And yet the result depends on the sort. Why?

Comment: I can only guess that there is a sort in the `ml model` code.

Comment: There isn't, at least as far as I can see there isn't (see edit to my original question).

Comment: an expression `1-\`r'` always rings alarmbells with me, see [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0025). Is `\`r'` a number between 0 and 1? Than I would change the `args` line to `args lnf logitminusr ...` and add the lines `tempname oneminusr` and `scalar \`oneminusr' = invlogit(-\`logitminusr')`. and change the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: No, `r` can take on any value (except 1, obviously). Is your concern that if `r` is very close to 1 any imprecision will be amplified immensely in the division?

Comment: That would be a problem too, but I was more worried by the issue discussed in the paper I linked to before. [Here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0025) is the link again.

Comment: Very interesting (also: scary!). Thanks for the reference. If I understand this correctly, this would be a reason to distrust the output of the function. What I don't yet understand is how it would interact with the sorting of the data I pass into the function to produce different results depending on the sorting.

Comment: Neither do I understand the dependence on the sort order. I just checked for a simple user written probit model and in that case `ml`  is not dependent on the sort order in the data (as it should be), so I guess there is somehting special aobut your code that is causing it. Maybe you can contact [Stata's tech support](http://www.stata.com/support/tech-support/)?

Comment: Like I said at the beginning: The parameter that moves around is only weakly identified - if at all (it's not my model. I'm trying to replicate someone else's analysis). The differences between the likelihoods at the parameter values Stata estimates in different runs are tiny, so tiny that precision issues may well play a role. Nonetheless I will contact Stata support and ask about why this is happening.

Comment: For all who are still interested: Stata support says that this numerical instability comes from a combination of the weak identification of the model and the fact that in floating point arithmetic the order of the summands may matter if you add numbers (try out `di %25.0g 0.3+0.6+0.1` vs `di %25.0g 0.3+0.1+0.6`). And since the log-likelihood is just a sum of the log-likelihoods of individual observations the log-likelihood will differ depending on how the data is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337670/2071807), adding the option `stable` to my `sort` command made the difference in my situation.